# pre-defined function called before main

Tags: c++, c

I don't understand how and when the call to this pre-defined function `sqrt()` is made, also in case if i define my own function `sqrt()` it shows a compilation error, so why a pre-defined function call works and call to user-defined function fails although both code resides in the (TEXT) section of my executable.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int x = sqrt(16); 

int main()
{

     printf(" x =  %d\n",x);
     return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
x = 4;
```

When i am calling sqrt() function defined by me i am getting following error but the same error does'nt show up when i am using a pre-defined function

ERROR : initializer element is not constant

Comment: You have tagged this question both C and C++. They are two different languages, with different rules for initializing variables.

Comment: Also, you don't say _which_ compilation error you get. I can see two possibilities, depending on if you remove the include of math.h or not when you define your sqrt function, and how that function is written.

Answer (score 8):

If you define your own `sqrt` function, it will clash with the one already defined in `math.h`, ergo the error.

The call is made because globals (or, rather, namespace scope variables) are initialized before entry to `main` - the initialization of `x` that is.

Comment: NO, actually function name does'nt matter, even if i change the name it does'nt work. My question is when my executable is created it contains code for the pre-defined function and it is called before main() and value id assigned to "X", similarly if i write my own function it should also work ,i mean what is the problem with it.

Comment: @curious you can use Preprocessor directives for your problem.

Comment: @curious did you declare your function before using it?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes i have declared my function before using it.

Comment: @curious if this isn't the issue, don't you think posting your actual code with the actual error be better? Just a thought...

Answer (score 5):

In C, an initializer to a variable with static storage duration (which means that it's there during the whole life time of the program, such as your **x**) must be a constant expression. A call to a function is not a constant expression, and you'll get a compiler error such as (from GCC) **error: initializer element is not constant**. The standard also says that "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions", so it is allowed for the compiler to accept a call to a library function such as **sqrt** as a constant expression. The compiler knows what **sqrt** will do, and can even evaluate it during compilation and replace the function call with its result.

C++ has different rules, and there you're allowed to call functions, even your own functions, when initializing **x**.

Comment: Maybeeeeee, initially i thought the same but the libraries are in the form of binaries, it's hard to imagine how compiler does it because it has to run that code and get the result ( It is the only way perhaps) , i seriously doubt it does it that way. can you provide few reference ??

Comment: @curious: The statements about initializers and constant expressions are from (my free draft copy of) the standard document, but if you want references to how GCC works internally I can only refer you to GCC documentation and source code. I did, however, use **nm** to list the symbols contained in the compiled executable of your program, and one program that calls **sqrt** with a variable as argument, and while the latter program contains the symbol **sqrt@@GLIBC_2.2.5**, your program does not, which indicates that the call to **sqrt** in your program has been eliminated by the compiler.

Comment: After all, GCC is a C program, and it can call **sqrt** just like any other C program.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc compiler compiles the source file in a procedural manner.

> Use g++ or c++ compiler.The code will work perfectly

I compiled the code using g++ compiler and compilation was successfull.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int mysqrt(int n)
{
return(n);
}
int a=mysqrt(10);

int main()
{
printf("%d",a);
return(0);
}
```

Please ignore the internal logic of mysqrt function.It is just for testing purpose.

From my knowledge it is a problem with gcc compiler.

Clause 6.6, paragraph 3 of the standard says

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment,
>   decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are
>   contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.

that a constant expression must not contain a function-call that is evaluated.

That is because

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than
>   runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may
>   be.

The gcc compiler is able to evaluate a constant express by executing a library function at compile time.But it is unable to evaluate a constant express by executing a user defined function at compile time.But the g++ and c++ compilers are able to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

It saying that one function by the name sqrt() is defined else already (math.h has its declaration)

when you add the math.h header file it contains the declaration for sqrt() function which is in library which will be added while linking.

when you try to define your own function by the same name compiler gets confused on which function to call (your's or the one already declared in math.h)

Change your function name to  my_sqrt() it should work fine when you define and call.

Note: try to learn about comiplation process. what happens at each stage you will get a better picture of what's happpening.

Comment: Actually i haven't included <math.h> in my code,i just wrote here to be more explicit.My question to you is same i asked in above answer

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by the reason Luchian explained above.

To be precise with your problem, you need to understand **[Preprocessor Directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).**

> Preprocessor directives are lines included in the code of programs
>   preceded by a hash sign (#). These lines are not program statements
>   but directives for the preprocessor. The preprocessor examines the
>   code before actual compilation of code begins and resolves all these
>   directives before any code is actually generated by regular
>   statements.

You can simply define x before entering main function by:

```
 #define x BLAH
```

I think this will clear bit of your thoughts. Cheerss!

Comment: What? I don't understand this answer at all.

Comment: I am explaining a bit of preprocessor directive here. Let me add more clearification for better understanding.

Comment: I am still confused. What do preprocessor directives have to do with this question?

Comment: A problem he is facing about defining x before entering main function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the function in an another file and and include the file here it will.work . Or just simply declare the function before intialization

Comment: Just try to define before calling